# Nested directory nuxt 3 + Vite

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I want to use nested directory in nuxt 3 beta with vite.

In Nuxt 2 i was using this config in (nuxt.config.js) and it work :

```
components: [
{
  path: '~/components', // will get any components nested in let's say /components/test too
  pathPrefix: false,
},],
```

I have this directory organisation:

```
| components
 - Header.vue
 - Footer.vue
 | sections
  - HeroSection.vue
```

but i got this error when i try to put `<HeroSection/>` in `pages/index.vue`.

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: HeroSection
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.
Invalid value used as weak map key
```

does it no longer work in nuxt 3 and there is another configuration to do? Because I find nothing about it on the doc

Thank <3

Answer (score 1):

Using nested directories requires prepending the name of the directory onto the component:

```html
<template>
  <SectionsHeroSection />
</template>
```

With this behavior you can be less complex about naming your components:

```
- components
    Header.vue
    Footer.vue
  - Sections
      Hero.vue
```

So that we can use like so

```html
<template>
  <SectionsHero />
</template>
```

Read more in the docs here: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/components#component-names

Comment: I agree with this, but I really want them to put this feature like in nuxt 2 to have the same directory architecture and component names

Comment: @Macsim if your component's parent folder is the same name as the component, you can simply write the component name.

Answer (score 0):

I found this on the doc:

```
import { join } from 'pathe'
import { defineNuxtModule } from '@nuxt/kit'

export default defineNuxtModule({
  hooks: {
    'components:dirs'(dirs) {
      // Add ./components dir to the list
      dirs.push({
        path: join(__dirname, 'components'),
        prefix: 'awesome'
      })
    }
  }
})
```

https://v3.nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/components/

But it desn't work with this config:

```
hooks: {
    'components:dirs'(dirs) {
      // Add ./components dir to the list
      dirs.push({
        path: join(__dirname, 'components/sections'),
        prefix: false
      })
    }
  }
```